# What does "the way of" mean in "To the deer it is a reminder of the way of all flesh ... "?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does "the way of" mean in:

> A deep chesty bawl echoes from rimrock to rimrock, rolls down the mountain, and fades into the far blackness of the night. … Every living thing (and perhaps many a dead one as well) pays heed to that call. To the deer it is a reminder of **the way of all flesh**, to the pine a forecast of midnight scuffles and of blood upon the snow, to the coyote a promise of gleanings to come, to the cowman a threat of red ink at the bank, to the hunter a challenge of fang against bullet. … Only the mountain has lived long enough to listen objectively to the howl of a wolf.

Context: [*Thinking Like a Mountain* By Aldo Leopold](http://www.eco-action.org/dt/thinking.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Way*** means both a course of travel or movement, and a means of passing from one place or point to another, especially of entry or exit. It is widely used for both literal and figurative purposes. (OED)

***The way of all flesh*** refers to experience common to all people as they pass through life.

> 2002   NFT Programme Booklet Sept. 11/1   *Stroheim's cruelly ironic tale of a rakish Ruritanian aristocrat..who falls for an innocent young girl.., only for their love to go **the way of all flesh**.*

***To go the way of all flesh*** is a euphemism for dying

> 1836   Dickens Sketches by Boz 1st Ser. II. 27   *He pardoned us off-hand, and allowed us something to live upon, till **he went the way of all flesh***.

***The way(s) of the world*** uses 'way' in a similar fashion (meaning the customary course of events; the manner in which people typically think or behave; the way things are. Chiefly used to express resigned acceptance of a regrettable but predictable state of affairs).

Comment: The *In the way of* phrase is irrelevant here. One goes *the way of all flesh*, not *in the way of all flesh*.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: not necessarily. Given that "the way of all flesh" is a truncated phrase with an implied meaning essentially, it's equally valid to say that *one goes the way of all flesh* (when one dies), as it is to say that *one's children and grandchildren will eventually die, in the way of all flesh*. This is not, however, the same as something *getting in the way of all flesh*, which would possibly represent a very persistent and universal type of obstacle.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the use of "flesh" here is an example of *synecdoche*, where a part (flesh) is used to refer to a whole (an entire being that has flesh, or a large group of such beings).

Answer (score 7):

*the way of all flesh* is an idiom for *death*.

> **go the way of all flesh**
>   1. To die.
>   2. To come to an end.
>    [American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+the+way+of+all+flesh)

The quoted sentence means:
*To the deer it is a reminder of its own mortality.*

Answer (score 3):

"The way of all flesh" is an idiom meaning *mortality*. The origin is unclear, but [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/go-the-way-of-all-flesh) thinks it a misquotation from the Bible.

Comment: It's the title of a posthumously published novel by Samuel Butler (the 19th-century *Erewhon* Samuel Butler, not the 17th-century *Hudibras* Samuel Butler) which was hugely admired in the first third of the 20th century and still regarded as a minor classic. Butler conflates (I think deliberately) two biblical expressions, "The way of all the earth" and "All flesh is grass".

Comment: I would call it a mistranslation, rather than a misquotation; it appears as such in the Douay-Rheims Bible. Or at least it's beyond me, why one would translate 'terrae' from the Vulgate as 'flesh'. I am not a theologian however.